# form submission in Drupal

Tags: 7, hooks

i have made a custom module for form in drupal using dupal API,and made a table in my database...now What i want is to save the value of drop down box instead of it's index into database...my .module file is:

```
<?php
function form_test_menu() {
$items['formtest'] = array(
'title' => 'Form Test',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('form_test_form'),
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}
function form_test_form($form,&$form_submit) {
$form['name'] = array(
'#title' => t('Name'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['college'] = array(
'#title' => t('College/University'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['education'] = array(
'#title' => t('Education'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#description' => 'Select your higher education .',
'#options' => array(t('--- SELECT ---'), t('B.tech'), t('MCA'), t('MBA'),t('Graduate')),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['percentage'] = array(
'#title' => t('Percentage/CGPA'),
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['application'] = array(
'#title' => t('Job Applied'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#options' => array(t('---select---'),t('Web Developer'),t('Web Designer'),t('SEO'),t('Marketing')),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['submit'] = array(
'#value' => 'Submit',
'#type' => 'submit',
);
return $form;
}
function form_test_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
global $user;
db_insert('drupal')
->fields(array(
'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
    'college' => $form_state['values']['college'],
    'education' => $form_state['values']['education'],
    'percentage' => $form_state['values']['percentage'],
    'application' => $form_state['values']['application'],

))->execute();
drupal_set_message("successfully saved data");
} ?>
```

any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to make the key the same as the value.  For instance:

```
$form['education'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Education'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#description' => 'Select your higher education.',
  '#options' => array(
    '_none' => t('-- SELECT --'),
    'B.tech' => t('B.tech'),
    'MCA' => t('MCA'),
    'MBA' => t('MBA'),
    'Graduate' => t('Graduate')
  ),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

You need to pass values in associative array

Comment: Life saver....Thanks Darvanen...it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You just build associative array for options.

```
'#options' => array('select'=>'select','Web Developer'=>'Web Developer','Web Designer'=>'Web Designer','SEO'=>'SEO','Marketing'=>'Marketing'),
```

Comment: Welcome @Nainesh enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't accepted the answer yet, i want to suggest another approach.. I don't know why but I don't like to declare select option keys as its values(may be the reason is keys are used for systems, values are for users, may be its fine to set them the same..).

Form submit function accepts to arguments - `$form, $form_state`, you know what `form_state` is for.. And `form` argument holds the full state of the form with its fields and their configs and so on.. My suggestion is to get form select option values by `$form` arguemnt (by this way you don't need to worry how keys will be declared..):

Here is an example:

```
...
$form['education'] = array(
'#title' => t('Education'),
'#type' => 'select',
'#description' => 'Select your higher education .',
'#options' => array(t('--- SELECT ---'), t('B.tech'), t('MCA'), t('MBA'),t('Graduate')),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
...
```

form submit function:

```
function form_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// we're getting the education select key
$educationKey = $form_state['values']['education'];

// here is the education select value
$educationValue = $form['education']['#options'][$educationKey];
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks xurshid...i have done the same and it worked...can you point towards some tutorials on retriving data from database using db_select()?...that's my next task

Comment: @NaineshPathak Hi, here is a [good tutorial](http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/88), but in russian (I think you can understand it from code), and here is a [good examples](http://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/sql-query-examples-drupal-7)

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way to create the associative array is with [`drupal_map_assoc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_map_assoc/7)

```
drupal_map_assoc(array(t('Value 1'), t('Value 2'), t('Value 3')))
```

e.g:

```
$form['education'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Education'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#description' => 'Select your higher education .',
  '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(t('--- SELECT ---'), t('B.tech'), t('MCA'), t('MBA'),t('Graduate'))),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

The array keys will then match the values.

Watch the use of t() in the array keys though, as if translations exist the stored value will be the translated string. You may prefer to hard code a single language/string for the array keys instead.

e.g:

```
array('value_1' => t('Value 1'), 'value_2' => t('Value 2'), 'value_3' => t('Value 3'))
```